# Laravel 4 IoC Container - Setting Up & Using Providers

Tags: php, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to use http://geotools-php.org/ in Laravel 4 (L4).

I followed the instructions for downloading through Composer (and verified geotools existance in the vendors folder).

I added "app/providers/GeoTools.php" to my autoload classmap.

Here's the contents:

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
        "toin0u/geotools": "@stable"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            ... more laravel stuff
            "app/providers/GeoTools.php"
        ]
    }
    ... more laravel stuff
```

I created /providers/GeoTools.php file.

Here are the contents:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class GeoToolsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('Coordinate', function()
        {

            return new Geotools\Coordinate;

        });
    }

}
```

In my app.php providers array I added "GeoToolsServiceProvider".

Here are my questions:

1. Obviously I have done something wrong, how *should* this be done.
2. Once you have the above code correct how do you properly use it throughout the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of this library.

It's not possible (for the moment Laravel Bêta 5) to bind the `Geotools\Coordinate\Coordinate` class like you wanted to do because the Laravel IoC Container doest not accept arguments without default values or types (i.e. interfaces / classes) which are [automatically resolved](http://four.laravel.com/docs/ioc#automatic-resolution) by Reflection. The [container](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php) will throw an `BindingResolutionException` exception.

The best way is to extend the `Geotools` class and add a method which will create `Coordinate` instances.

I'm waiting for the stable version of Laravel 4 before to make any BC breaks in Geotools.

I just made the [Geotools package](https://github.com/toin0u/Geotools-laravel) for Laravel 4. I hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

The service provider looks okay actually. The issues are probably in autoloading and without seeing how you added to the class map its hard to tell what is going on. As far as usage try the following,

```
class Foo {

   protected $coordinate;

   public function __construct(Coordinate $coordinate)
   {
       $this->coordinate = $coordinate
   }
}
```

Comment: This answer has me totally confused.  It's not like any example I've seen before.  I updated the question to show the classmap file and the implementation in providers has always been there.  I am having trouble using this code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be ables to access the instance by using the app facade

```
App::make('Coordinate')->$someGeotoolCoordinateFunction();
```

Comment: Ok, I get how to use it now, thank you.  Now,  it is telling me that the class is not found on that line in my app.php (which was actually encouraging to me).  There has to be one more thing I'm missing.  I updated the question with a little more data.

Comment: It seems like your setup is correct. check that the geotools namespacing is correct (from the package source, I can tell it's probably Geotools\Coordinate\Coordinate) and run 'composer dumpautoload' for good measure. In your composer.json file under providers, it may be more effective to use 'app/providers'.